# Is it possible to add class for main route DOMelement?

Tags: ember.js

As in title, is it possible to add something like

> classNames

in Component but inside Route or Controller object?

---

**Edited**

In application template I add few elements

```
<header></header>
<div class="content"></div>
<footer></footer>
```

And as result on page I have:

```
<div id="ember1122" class="ember-view">
  <header></header>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <footer></footer>
</div>
```

And I'd like to have

```
<div id="ember1122" class="ember-view customClassName">
```

Comment: How about sending class an argument while including component like {{my-component class=myClassPropertyName}}`

Comment: I described it more precisely :) I'd like to not use additional component for this

Answer (score 0):

At present, you can't do what you want in a straight forward way.
1. But you can wrap `application.hbs` content with root div.

Define `rootElement` in index.html

```
<div id="my-app" class="customClassName">
  {{content-for "body"}}
</div>
```

inside `app.js` file, you can change [`rootElement`](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.11.0/configuring-ember/embedding-applications/#toc_changing-the-root-element)

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Application.extend({
  rootElement: '#my-app'
});
```

2.May be you can even try applying styles to application.hbs div using css like
 `#my-app > .ember-view { // customClassName style goes here }`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. Altough documentation states that "controller is a specialized component", in fact they are not at all similar.

Component is a subclass of `Ember.View`. Every time a Component is rendered, there's created a new instance that is hooked to specific part of DOM, has hooks related to rendering, and is aware of DOM elements that it contains.

Controller is an abstract singleton, subclass of `Ember.Object`. It has functions, properties and actions hooked to rendered template, but doesn't know itself anything about DOM it's attached to.